# How to translate svg g elements to cozy up with siblings?

Tags: svg, d3.js

```
var boxes = [[30, 45], [50, 30], [40, 30]];  // [w, h]

//Should i calculate `translate` value  here, adding all heights? 

var secs = wrapper.selectAll('g.section')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .attr('class', 'section')
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 'unknown' + ")");

//could be many sub-secs by a lot of data transformation before appending rect to the last one of them.

secs.append('rect')
     .datum(function(d){return d;})
     .attr('class', 'fragment')
     .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', function(d){return d[0];})
     .attr('height', function(d){return d[1];})

// or here, not from data but from elem's dimensions?

secs.each(function(sec, i){
  var prev = this.previousSibling?this.previousSibling.getBBox():'';
  var ty = prev?prev.height+ prev.y:0;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + ty + ")");
});
```

Is this how you translate `g` elements to fit their childrens, at any level of depth?
And i'll have to translate them manually when child expands?

i'm new at svg and d3.
Thank you.

Comment: You would usually put the `g` elements at pre-defined positions, e.g. by computing the size of the screen and the number of elements. Can you give us some context for this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: how'd i translate parent gs if all rects have variable height?  i don't know their heights but i need to offset the rect's parent

Comment: Depends on your context. Can you compute the height?

Comment: yes but only after appending `rect`

Comment: so i should dig in the arrays, calculate every child's w, h and only then create the wrapper?

Comment: if i do it by counting elems or sth like `i*200`, there's a lot of extra space in between or overlaps. Where do i translate `container g` after appending all children?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete example that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: It looks like you would need to keep track of the sum of heights and translate by that.

Comment: yes, i have done that using global variables or object classes, is this how you all do it?

Comment: That certainly sounds like a feasible way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, had a great session with you.

Comment: i'd accept if you posted that 'tracking' comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would need to keep track of the sum of heights and translate by that. That is, for each rectangle that you add add its height to a total which you can then use to offset subsequent elements.